# Cuantas ImageView se puede agregar en un relative layout?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-imageview, scroll-view, linearlayout

estoy trabajando con android studio, cree una aplicacion que permite leer un comic. Ahora bien, yo clasifico a los comics por capitulos, cree una activiti donde se puede escoger desde que capitulo puedes empezar a leer.

Para que entiendan un poco mi codigo, uso un scroll view para que sea deslizante, dentro del scroll view esta el linear layout pero como en linear layout no puedo poner una imagen a lado de otra le puse un relative layout dentro, hay ya pude ubicar la imagen como queria... para cada imagen le puse un relative layout. a continuacion les agrego mi codigo xml

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".dragonball">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView4"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="410dp"
            android:layout_height="2000dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="410dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/alfa1"
                    android:layout_width="190dp"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:onClick="alfa1"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/multiverse"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="410dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:layout_width="190dp"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/multi2" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="58dp"
                    android:layout_height="73dp"
                    android:onClick="imageView8"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/atras" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="410dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:layout_width="190dp"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
                    android:onClick="imageView9"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/multi3"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="410dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                    android:layout_width="190dp"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                    android:onClick="imageView11"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/multi5"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   


codigo en java

package com.example.myapplication;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import DBmultiverse.pag1multiverse;
import DBmultiverse.pag2multiverse;
import DBmultiverse.pag3multiverse;
import DBmultiverse.pag4multiverse;
import DBmultiverse.pag5multiverse;
public class dragonball extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dragonball);
    }
    public void alfa1(View view){
        Intent alfa1 = new Intent(this, pag1multiverse.class);
        startActivity(alfa1);
    }
    public void imageView10(View view){
        Intent imageView10 = new Intent(this, pag2multiverse.class);
        startActivity(imageView10);
    }
    public void imageView8(View view){
        Intent imageView8 = new Intent(this,menumanga.class);
        startActivity(imageView8);
    }
    public void imageView9(View view){
        Intent imageView9 = new Intent(this, pag3multiverse.class);
        startActivity(imageView9);
    }
    public void imageView11(View view){
        Intent imageView11 = new Intent(this, pag5multiverse.class);
        startActivity(imageView11);
    }
}
```

por favor, tomen en cuenta que todas las clases que llamo en java ya estan creadas y todo funciona correctamente, es mas al hacer clic en las imagenes borrosas, si me llevan al capitulo que es. El unico problema es como les digo, las imagenes me aparecen borrosas. nose como hacer, ya he cambiado y buscado por todo lado, y no encuentro solucion.

Nota: cree un realtive layout para cada imagen, ya que al crear un solo layout y expandirlo en toda la pantalla, el scroll view dejaba de funcionar.

[image: asi es como deberia aparece]
[image: y asi es como me sale, la primera imagen sale bien, el resto que pongo salen borrosas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaja, ya veo que en esta comunidad ayudan demasiado xD...
bueno para los que le interesen y se encuentren en el mismo problema que yo tenia.
Estuve revisando todos mis codigos, y por lo visto no era error de codigo. lo que si me di cuenta mediante busqueda, revise el tipo de imagen que estaba agregando en el mipmap[image: la unica imagen que me aparecia era el de nombre "multiverse.jpg" con formato xxhdpi, el resto de imagenes esta en formato anydpi formato muy pequeño para visualizar, por ende me aparecia la imagen pixeleada]

[image: Asi es como queria solucionarlo...]

Espero le sirva alguna persona...

Comment: A mi también me pasa lo de que no me ayuden :( . Si ves que la respuesta es definitiva marcala como la respuesta destacada.